# TextView setBackground() doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I'm new to Android and I have the following problem:

I wanted to set TextView's background to #333. I used:

```
    TextView title = new TextView(this);  
    title.setText(currentContinent); 
    title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
    title.setBackgroundColor(0x333333);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Even though Eclipse marks no errors, TextView still has transparent background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the background color of the layout behind the TextView?

Comment: I checked with red for sure (app uses Holo Dark), but it's not a problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was creating a numeric color without considering the leading alpha channel. ie. `mytext.setTextColor(0xFF0000)` (thinking this would be red ). While this is a red color it is also 100% transparent as it = `0x00FF0000`; The correct 100% opaque value is `0xFFFF0000` or `mytext.setTextcolor(0xFFFF0000).`

In your case make it: `mytext.setTextcolor(0x33333333)`

Comment: I used `COLOR.RED`, but also checked this option, works fine. Thanks ;)

Comment: Actually, he'd probably want 0xFF333333. Good answer anyway, though.

Comment: You are welcome Kikert. Thanks for correcting my answer Eric!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
```

Provide the rgb component values in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView title = new TextView(this);  
title.setText(currentContinent); 
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
title.setBackgroundColor(0x33333333);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Try this..,.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any color using this:

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BCDABA")); // set any custom color as  
//background    color
```

or

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // set default GREEN color as background color
```

Comment: Based on comment, Color.GREEN or Color.RED?